Does Next.js middleware run again after redirect / rewrite?
I have read all I could find on the topic and was still unable to answer the following:
Assuming Next.js middleware runs on all routes, does it run again after itself has returned a redirect / rewrite response to the client, or does it somehow only run once for a particular request?
The question came up as I encountered an infinite loop of redirects, leading me to wonder if it does in fact run again after it returned a NextResponse.redirect / NextResponse.rewrite.

But the doc says middleware is for running code before request is completed. If twice is not mentioned we have to assume it runs once. Here is a similar question asking about express: https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/wl9phk/express_question_why_doesnt_my_middleware_get/. Since nextjs also uses express, I would say it is safe to assume it only runs the next function in stack once. Image: https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--PHYkGiKU--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/i/73eusy0bc095c9w8tstw.png

@TusharShahi Thanks, I did not know it used Express. If it does not run twice, then how come we can end up in infinite middleware loops, if not the right conditional checks are implemented? Is that only for NextResponse.redirect? Is NextResponse.redirect the only return value / Response value that makes the browser, i.e. client, make a trip back to the server?

Yes. I was looking at the commit here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/7209/files. Check the statement await DocumentMiddleware(ctx). It seems to be called only once in the renderToHTML function. Since redirect takes to a new route, the middleware is run again. From the docs: Middleware runs after redirects in next.config.js and before rendering.

Since middleware runs code before a request is completed, it is bound to run again if the middleware itself redirects to a different path in the app.
The middleware does not run twice in itself. This change introducing the middleware shows that.
  //inside renderToHTML

  if (typeof DocumentMiddleware === 'function') {
    await DocumentMiddleware(ctx)
  }

Now coming to NextResponse.redirect, the doc says that it returns a response which redirects.
The method is defined like:
  public redirect(destination: string, statusCode: number) {
    this.setHeader('Location', destination)
    this.statusCode = statusCode

    // Since IE11 doesn't support the 308 header add backwards
    // compatibility using refresh header
    if (statusCode === RedirectStatusCode.PermanentRedirect) {
      this.setHeader('Refresh', `0;url=${destination}`)
    }

    return this
  }

This sets the Location header, which means the browser is told to redirect to another URL.
This would trigger a request again and hence, run the middleware again.
